# Topology- the limited open intervals are homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I have a question concerning the open interval in a topological space $X$, given by
$$X = Y \times \{0\} \bigcup Z \times \{1\},$$
where $Z = \omega_{1} \times [0,1[$ and $Y = Z-\{(0,0)\}.$

I need to prove there is a function $\psi$ which has a homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}$.

*What I did:*
Evaluating the possibilities: I have three options: There is one interval in $Y \simeq \mathbb{R}$, one other $Z \simeq \mathbb{R}$ and finally an interval that begins in $Y$ and goes to $Z$.

Although, I can't still prove it $X \simeq \mathbb{R}$. How should I proceed?

Comment: $X$ has a disjoint sum topology?

Comment: it is disjoint.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is metrisable and separable so every subspace of $\Bbb R$ is separable. But $(\omega_1\times \{0\})\times \{1\}$ is a non-separable subspace of $X$ so $X$ cannot be homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Or does $X$ have a lexicographic ordering? That could also be and it’s different from the disjoint sum topology. So please specify the exact topology on $X$ and what you mean by an interval in it.

Comment: In either topology $X$ is **not** homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ but some small intervals in $X$ might be.

Comment: Hello, it has indeed a lexicograph order  $X = Y \times \{0\} \bigcup Z \times  \{1\}$ where $Z = \omega_{1} \times [0,1[$ and $Y = Z-\{(0,0)\} $,  $X \simeq \mathbb{R}$. We know that $Z$ has a order $(\alpha, x) <_{Y} (\beta, y)$ if we have$\alpha < \beta$ or $\alpha = \beta $ e $x<y$,  and $Y$ has a reverse order in $Z-\{(0,0)\}$.\\